# Sort objects by Group and Date, and keep only latest object in each Group

Tags: algorithm, sorting

An object contains, at least, the two fields Group and Date

```
interface Object {
   group: Integer
   date: Date
   ...
}
```

Then given an array of several Objects

```
array: Objects[] <- getAllObjects()
```

Find the latest object in each group. Or perhaps more general: for each distinct group, extract the highest value.

One approach is to map the objects by group, then for each group, sort the objects in that group by descending order and extract the first element.

```
function takes Array: Objects[] returns Object[] begin
   
   map: Map<Group, Object[]> <- empty map

   for each Object in Array do
      if (map contains key Object.group) then
         objectArray <- get value by key Object.group from map
         add Object to objectArray
      else then
         objectArray <- empty array 
         add Object to objectArray
         add value objectArray to map with key Object.group
      end
   end

   returnArray: Objects[] <- empty array

   for each Group in Map
      objectArray <- get value by key Group from Map
      sort objectArray by Object.date, descending
      latestObjectInGroup <- pop objectArray
      add latestObjectInGroup to returnArray
   end

   return returnArray
end
```

My question is: is there a simpler (e.g., less complex, more concise, less convoluted) algorithm for accomplishing this goal? Any programming language or library may be used, including Map/List-functions such as Sort, Reduce, Map, Filter, Collect etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the sorting.

Create a map with key=group value = objectWithHigestValueYet

And update the value whenever you see a higherValue for this group.

```
function takes Array: Objects[] returns Object[] begin
   
   map: Map<Group, Object[]> <- empty map

   for each Object in Array do
      if (map contains key Object.group) then
         oldHighestObject <- get value by key Object.group from map
         if(oldHighestObject.value<Object.value)         
           map.put(Object.group, Object)    // replace the old entry by this new one with higher value
      else then
         add value Object to map with key Object.group
      end
   end

   returnArray: Objects[] <- empty array

   for each Group in Map
      objec <- get value by key Group from Map
      add objec to returnArray
   end

   return returnArray
end
```